# Error with Google Sheets script – insert formula into cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm getting this error trying to create a script for a workbook:

*Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 5 file: Add Import Range Formula.gs*

I'm trying to create a script that will insert my formula into a cell... here's the formula itself (which includes calling another script).

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H7tXnwHS37SSFbnQGAl0aQujCSzzf3oKvvjLg7fdwVs/edit#gid=149220930","Master Roster!A:B"), INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H7tXnwHS37SSFbnQGAl0aQujCSzzf3oKvvjLg7fdwVs/edit#gid=149220930","Master Roster!A:C"),0,3)=GetSheetName())
```

It's working great when I paste it manually into my cell, but I'm unsure why the script won't accept it.

Here's the full script I'm trying to get working:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cell = sheet.getRange("c2");
cell.setFormula("=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H7tXnwHS37SSFbnQGAl0aQujCSzzf3oKvvjLg7fdwVs/edit#gid=149220930","Master Roster!A:B"), INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H7tXnwHS37SSFbnQGAl0aQujCSzzf3oKvvjLg7fdwVs/edit#gid=149220930","Master Roster!A:C"),0,3)=GetSheetName())");
```

Any help how to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape some of the quotes. Also, `query()` is easier here than `filter()`. Try this:

`cell.setFormula('=query(importrange("1H7tXnwHS37SSFbnQGAl0aQujCSzzf3oKvvjLg7fdwVs", "Master Roster!A1:B"), "where Col3 = \'" & GetSheetName() & "\' ", 1)');`

Note that your code will insert a formula in the "first" sheet, i.e., the one that appears leftmost in the tab bar. It will still do the same when the first sheet has been hidden, so check the hamburger menu ≣ in the tab bar to see if your first sheet is not currently visible.

Comment: Thanks.

I'm trying to get this working, and it's not.

I'm backing up to simply getting the script to insert a formula into the cell, with no success.

Here's what I'm testing with right now. Where's my problem at?

function addImportRangeFunctionToWorksheet() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
sheet.getRange("F2").setFormula("=4");
}

Comment: Edited the answer to discuss where the code inserts the formula.